# Adding element at end of a linked list, in function the pointer value not getting assigned? (using code::blocks)

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, codeblocks, singly-linked-list

I have been trying to implement function to add element at the end of an linked list but it is not working.

I tried to debug code in code::blocks and found that "h->next = newNode;" is not assigning the value.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node{
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

void printlist(Node* h){
    while(h->next!=nullptr){//or h!=0
        cout<<h->data<<endl;
        h = h->next;
    }
}

void pushend(Node* h, int newData){
    Node* newNode;
    newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = newData;
    newNode->next = nullptr;
    while(h!=nullptr){
        if(h->next == nullptr){
            h->next = newNode;
            break;
        }
        h = h->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    Node* head;
    Node* second;
    Node* third;   
    head = new Node;
    second = new Node;
    third = new Node;  
    head->data = 1;
    head->next = second;  
    second->data = 2;
    second->next = third; 
    third->data = 3;
    third->next = nullptr;
    int newData = 4;
    pushend(head,newData);
    printlist(head);
}
```

Comment: This won't compile. `- >` is not a valid spelling of `->`.

Comment: Please, first extract a [mcve], only then think about asking here. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: sorry about that I used https://codebeautify.org/c-formatter-beautifier to correct the indentation but it screwed it

Comment: I have corrected it now, please check. sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by `h->next = newNode; is not assigning the value`.

I can see that you are making a list with {1, 2, 3} as data, and than adding a 4 to the end - and I can also see that your print only prints `1, 2, 3`. But that is not caused by an error in `pushend`. Instead it is because your `printlist` uses a `while (h->next != nullptr)` loop, which means that it will never print your last element (and that it will crash if you ever call it on an empty list (`h = nullptr`)).

Change your `printlist` loop to `while (h != nullptr)` and all four elements will be printed.

Comment: Got it, Thanks.
Took me a while to understand, really sleepy.